# How can I know the number of rows/columns in an undefined array of pointers to a string in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, sizeof

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){

char*s[]={"we will teach you how to","Move a mountain","Level a building","Erase the past","Make a million"};

   printf("%u",sizeof(s));

return 0; }
```

Running this will output 20.
Shouldn't the size be = no.of elements in each array x no of arrays x sizeof(char)?
Also sizeof(s+1) prints 4 bytes. 
Furthermore, how can I obtain the number of pointer arrays and no. of elements in each pointer array from the above mentioned code without hard coding?

Comment: see my answer will help your program

Answer (score 1):

There are 5 entries in your array `s`. Each entry is a `char *`. Hence `sizeof(s)` is `5*sizeof(char *)`. It appears you are running on a 32 bit system so pointers are 4 bytes in size. Hence the total size is 20 bytes.

> how can I obtain the number of pointer arrays and no. of elements in each pointer array

That part of the question is a bit unclear. There is only one "pointer array" which is `s`. To get the number of elements in the array you can do:

```
sizeof(s) / sizeof(*s)
```

To get the length of the string at array index `i` you can do:

```
strlen(s[i])
```

Comment: The reason I asked is so that I can use it in a for loop to count the number of occurences of the letter 'e'. So i was unclear as to how to get the number of elements. Is it okay to use the condition s[i]!='\0' ?

Comment: No it's not ok. It's a type error. `s[i]` is of type `char *`. `'\0'` is of type `char`. You cannot compare these two types to each other.

Comment: @VinodAntony the only way a check like `s[i] != NULL` works is if you set a *sentinel* `NULL` as the next pointer after the last valid pointer in your array. (the same way `char *argv[]` does, or that `execv`, `execvp`, and `execve` require)